# bitnami PGPOOL pod won't start : /opt/bitnami/pgpool/conf/pool_hba.conf: Read-only file system

Tags: kubernetes, bitnami, pgpool

I'm trying to deploy pgpool using docker.io/bitnami/pgpool:4.2.3-debian-10-r38 image but the container fails to start due to this error
`pgpool 09:10:02.55 INFO  ==> Initializing Pgpool-II... pgpool 09:10:02.59 INFO  ==> Generating pg_hba.conf file... /opt/bitnami/scripts/libpgpool.sh: line 348: /opt/bitnami/pgpool/conf/pool_hba.conf: Read-only file system`

even though the volume mount read only parameter is set to false and i'm running as root user

yaml file used:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: pgpool-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pgpool
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pgpool
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
        fsGroup: 0
        runAsGroup: 0
      containers:
        - name: pgpool
          image: docker.io/bitnami/pgpool:4.2.3-debian-10-r38
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 0
            runAsGroup: 0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          env:
            - name: PGPOOL_BACKEND_NODES
              value: "0:postgres-0.postgres:5432,1:postgres-1.postgres:5432,2:postgres-2.postgres:5432"
            - name: PGPOOL_ADMIN_USERNAME
              value: "admin"
            - name: PGPOOL_ADMIN_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: pgpool-secrets
                  key: admin-password
            - name: PGPOOL_POSTGRES_USERNAME
              value: "postgres"
            - name: PGPOOL_POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-creds
                  key: password
            - name: PGPOOL_HEALTH_CHECK_USER
              value: "postgres"
            - name: PGPOOL_HEALTH_CHECK_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-creds
                  key: password
            - name: PGPOOL_SR_CHECK_USER
              value: "postgres"
            - name: PGPOOL_SR_CHECK_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-creds
                  key: password
          volumeMounts:
            - name: pgpool-config
              mountPath: /opt/bitnami/pgpool/conf/
              readOnly: false
            - name: pgpool-tls
              mountPath: /etc/pgpool2
              readOnly: false
      volumes:
        - name: pgpool-config
          configMap:
            name: pgpool-config
        - name: pgpool-tls
          secret:
            secretName: pgpool-tls
```

any idea what could be the reason ?

the volume mount read only parameter is set to false and i'm running as root user